# How to get the target value of CreatableSelect (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have one of the forms using a react library called React Select. But I don't know how to get the target value of that input. My code is as follows:

```
# CreatableSelect tag
<CreatableSelect
    className={Astyle.selectInput}
    isClearable
    isMulti
    options={productsData}
    id="company_products"
    required
/>
```

[React-select-creatable](https://react-select.com/creatable)

I tried to use event.target to get the value. However, it doesn't work cuz it seems that this method can't get multiple value (or an array) using event.

```
# Get data from the form.
    const data = {
      name: event.target.company_name.value,
      url: event.target.company_url.value,
      description: event.target.company_desc.value,> tag: event.target.company_products.value
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no event handler used (like "onChange") and you added a "next.js" tag, I assume a standard form post is used (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data)

In order to make an input field work, there is a "name" attribute required.
There is no "name" property set for the CreatableSelect component in your example code. Maybe this is the problem ...